# How to get feedback from users in closed testing in google console

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-play, google-play-console

Hi am new in android development and i have add my email lists to closed testing .. 4 users has download and open the app but only 1 testers opted came in google play .. and also how to collect reviews from testers and where to see those review in google play? .. can any one solved my issue .

Comment: also can any one tell me when _ testers opted in came in google play console ?  when that number get increase

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Console usually refreshes user statistics once every 24 hours, so I guess this also is the case with the number of closed testers. Google Play Console however sometimes is not 100% reliable in updating the statistics regularly.

The test users can leave feedback to the app using the rating function in Google Play. Ratings provided at closed tests will not be publicly visible and do not affect your app's average rating. You then should be able to see these testing reviews under [this link](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/8612337217832066595/app/4974640535802978484/user-feedback/beta-feedback).

Comment: ok thanks and i want to know which count is measure for _ testers opted.. for example  if i install app that count measure or after installed if user open the app or given a feedback that count is measure?

Comment: I would say that the count is per download of the test app. But I haven't found any official documentation on that.

Comment: for some emails feedback not shown in console .. when to give review to app before installing the app or after?

Answer (score 0):

facing same issue i have added Tester email id's for the close testing and my tester downloaded app using link from the close testing they have also sent their feedback but still on dashboard it is showing just 2 tester are opt for the testing . their is no way to know which are those tester who has opt and how and when this tester count will increase. now its long time i am after this and i will loose my client because of this google strict policy.